# Assembly x86 - Addressing variables in memory (answer is provided, looking for an explanation)

Tags: assembly, x86

```
.DATA
STRING DB "ABCD", OFFH,-2,2,'2'
ARRAY DW 0ABCDH,12EFH,0,1,2
DOUBLE TIMES 2 1234ABCDH
```

The question is to draw that memory segment for each variable assuming starting address is 1000H

[image]

What I'm understanding is it's working in little endian format. I understand how STRING is formed in memory, but anything else after that I don't get, and why does the DOUBLE variable start at the 2nd row?

Comment: If you understand little endian, you should have no problem with the `ARRAY` after the `STRING`, right? That obviously takes you up to the `DOUBLE` so explains why that starts where it does. It's given in hex so you don't need to bother with floating point conversion.

Comment: @Jester I understand the ARRAY after the string until 0,1,2 aren't shown on the first row after EF

Comment: It's a `DW` so 2 bytes each. The row ends with `00 00 = 0` and `01 00 = 1`. Second row starts with `02 00 = 2` then the two doubles.

Comment: The first element of ARRAY is ABCD stored at addresses 1008 and 1009. The second element is 12EF stored at addresses 100A and 100B. The third element is 0000, stored at 100C and 100D, and so on.

Comment: @prl assuming we have var1 DD 0xadcaef87, how would that look like? since its a floating point number

Comment: 0xadcaef87 is **not** a floating point number.